# How can I create the following 4*4 Matrix from a 2*2 Matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4],[1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4]])
```

I want to convert a to b here. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We would need to know the rule that you want to implement; there are several rational ways to derive this specific case.  Also, please post your coding attempt -- these rational ways depend on coding techniques that are readily available from a tutorial on list handling.

Comment: @Prune: This is a NumPy array, not a list, so list techniques would be inappropriate.

Comment: Ah ... good point ... duh ... change that to "tutorial on NumPy array handling" ...

Comment: Thanks all, I got a  numpy lib to accomplish this. (np.tile())

Answer (score 0):

**For those curious**

Even though OP figured this out already: Here's how this can be achieve very easily

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.tile(a, (2, 2))  # (2, 2) = extend columns by 2 and rows by 2
>>> array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 3, 4],
           [1, 2, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 3, 4]])

np.tile(a, 2)  # 2 = extend columns by 2
>>> array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on *Bobs Burgers* post, but don't have enough reputation. I was playing with np.repeat, and that wasn't quite getting me there. The closest I achieved was:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> a.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

I like the `tile` answer, but this might be useful for people looking for something slightly different.